# converting keccak from old version: pragma solidity 0.4.19;

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solc, keccak

I am trying to compile following code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.9;
contract test{
//https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3469

address payable owner;
mapping (address => bool) pd;
uint public sS;
function lnA(address addr) public view returns(uint n) {
        // 1 in 8 chance
        n = uint(keccak256(uint(addr), sS)[0]) % 8;

    }
}
```

> solc keccakSyntaxerr.sol
>
> > keccakSyntaxerr.sol:10:18: Error: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1. This function
> >     requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain
> >     the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.
> >
> > n = uint(keccak256(uint(addr), sS)[0]) % 8;
> >                          ^-----------------------^
> >         keccakSyntaxerr.sol:10:13: Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "uint256".
> >                 n = uint(keccak256(uint(addr), sS)[0]) % 8;
> >                     ^--------------------------------^

How to convert the above syntax into lastest Solidity versions? Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to covert the arguments to a `bytes`. `abi.encodePacked(args)` is a way to do it.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.9;
contract test{
    //https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3469

    address payable owner;
    mapping (address => bool) pd;
    uint public sS;

    function lnA(address addr) public view returns(uint8 n) {
        // 1 in 8 chance
        n = uint8(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr, sS))[0]) % 8;
    }
}
```

I dropped `uint(addr)` because padding the address with extra zeroes isn't needed for the "1 in 8" objective described in the remark.

As a PSA: Be sure you fully understand the attack vectors for a game based on randomness if that is the goal. This is entirely predictable and an adversary can brute force it to get a desired result.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

The 1 byte step doesn't add any entropy to this (there isn't any). You can:

```
// 1 in 8 chance
n = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr, sS))) % 8;
```

Where `n` is a `uint`. That may save a little gas or be a little more readable.

Comment: In the last statement original code does not have uint8: What is the logic? If I try: n= uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr, sS))[0]) %8; I would get anerror, even though data type of 'n' is uint and not uint8. Why 'uint' is wrong? Somebody please guide me.

Comment: In previous compilers, conversion from 256-bit to 8-bit uint was implicit but now the rules require explicit conversion so the compiler can catch more errors. The `[0]` takes the first `byte` from the `bytes` returned from `abi.encode...` - 1 byte. That gets converted to `uint8` which is natural because a byte is 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks. What would happen to 'n', the receiver? Will it remain to 256? So we are not making the data compatible to the type of receiver. Does it mean that we can never convert from 8 bit to 256 bits?

Comment: I understand we are  doing it just because of the reason you stated above. Thanks. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Solidity won't let you mix up type casting between functions. You can _explicitly_ convert with `uint(uint8(3))` to pad with lots of `0` or you can `uint8(uint(256))` to discover how bits will be lost. The potentially disastrous effect of losing bits is a reason why the conversion has to be explicit. Another is it helps flag errors and oversights, which is a good thing. Think about the casting you want and stick to it. Usually the largest precision you will _ever_ need.

Comment: Can i get a link for 1 in 8 chance ? I am searching but can't find.

Comment: That remark is from the original question, so we assume that is part of the goal. % 8, modulo 8 is a number between 0 and 7.  You keccak looks like an attempt to make even distribution. Even distribution != random. See the warning in the answer.

Comment: n = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr, sS))) % 8; n is uint i.e 256 bits and keccak is also returning 256bits, why are we type casting the return value of keccak to uint?

Comment: In the code you are trying to convert, it is `uint8`. `uint` and `uint256` are the same. Conversions have to be explicit. Your 0-7 range of possible results will fit in a `uint8`. There are subtle considerations for optimization but the main thing is consistency.

Comment: keccak256(...) returns a byte32 value, that's we have to typecast return value of keccak256(....) to uint, link: https://www.edureka.co/community/22391/can-get-same-return-value-solidity-abi-encodepacked-golang, How bytes32 is same as uint8?

Comment: You are right '%' will return a remainder i.e. 0-7 value because we are dividing by 8. But I am concerned why we are using uint with keccak256(...). I thought keccak256(....) returns 256 bit value which is not correct.

Comment: It goes keccak =-> bytes32 which is convertable to uint256 which is convertable to uint8 (with loss of leftmost bits).